# send verification mail form my live site (domain email address) using cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, verification, webmail, email-verification

I'm working on a Project in Codeigniter which follows MVC pattern, I've created a Model to send Verification Email to my Website's Signed Up members. the code is working perfectly using Google's SMTP on `localhost` but now the site is LIVE and I don't know about protocols and Web-mail, as I'm new to this..
the `localhost` code is here:

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'My Mail', 
            'smtp_pass' => 'My Password', 
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
```

now what are the changes needed to use it through Web Mail CPanel??

Comment: can you put the code , which you are using to send email ?

Comment: Sir the code is working fine.. I just want to know that i am using webmail, what should i write in these lines..
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webmail settings you will find smtp settings.
Ports will be same in major case. you need to change host, username and password as per your new server.

There will be link "Configure Mail Client" in email section in case you are using standard cPanel setup and customization is not done by your hosting provider

## Edit

Ok, Here are the direct steps.

1. Login to your cPanel
2. Go to Emails Section
3. Go to Configure Mail Client
4. Now check details like host port etc.

'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', //this will be given on cpanel

'smtp_port' => 465,  //this will be given on cpanel

'smtp_user' => 'My Mail', // This will be email provided by your host so, username@domain.com

'smtp_pass' => 'My Password' // password for username@domain.com

PS: You can also use gmail settings that you are already using if it is your own site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really new to this.. do I have to use Outlook as my mail client?? I'm not getting please help..

Comment: Secure SSL/TLS Settings
(Recommended)
Username: My UserName
Password: My Password
Incoming Server: web2013.websitewelcome.com
Port 993
Port 995
Outgoing Server: web2013.websitewelcome.com
Port 465
Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.

Authentication is required.. How should I authenticate??

Comment: "ssl://web2013.websitewelcome.com" this will be your smtp_host and 465 will be smtp_port. Username and Password as per yours.